# How to get ShowState of a window in c# or c++?

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to get showstate of a window.

I know that I can maximize, minimize, or close a window by ShowWindow API in c# or c++. How do I get ShowState of a window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
GetWindowPlacement( hWnd, &wp );

UINT showCmd = wp.showCmd;
```